# Only displaying one radio button widget from a Django RadioSelect

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am making a form with Django, and need to manually lay out the form in the HTML. I have one field that's a `ChoiceField` and the widget is a `RadioSelect` (i.e. radio buttons rather than select drop down). There are 2 choices in this field (i.e. there will be 2 radio buttons when it's displayed).

If i do `{{ form.fieldname }}`, then it puts in both radio buttons there. I want to control where each radio button goes (since I need to put other things 'beside' each radio button, rather than just the textual value from the `choices` parameter).

I can manually enter the correct html `<input type="radio" name="fieldname"…`, however this won't reflect the value, if the field is set to the first choice then this HTML won't have `selected="selected"` on it.

Is there anyway, in the django template, to just put in the first radio button for a field? Something like this:

```
{{ form.fieldname.radio_button_0 }} (some of my custom html here)
Some more stuff {{ form.fieldname.radio_button_1 }} some more html here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has information on how to iterate over each radio button:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/

See "class RadioSelect".

Comment: Brilliant! That's just what I was looking for, and is included in the new development version of Django, so wasn't there when I posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try `form.fieldname.widget.renderer[%CHOICE%]`. For example if you have `choices = (('o', 'one'),('t', 'two'))`, then valid `%CHOICE%` would be `'o'` or `'t'`.

Comment: I tried that by putting in {{ form.fieldname.widget.renderer.CHOICE }} in the template, and nothing came out (i.e. it doesn't exist)

Comment: Have you replaced CHOICE with actual choice value? But I haven't tested it, sorry if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes I used the actual choice value.